# Spotify Integration in android

Tags: android, spotify

I have some doubts regarding *Spotify*.

1. How can I get the user id of a logged in user in *Spotify*. I have to use the user information in my application.
2. How to get the login status from S*potify*. The issue I am facing is when I tried to logged in for the first time, it works fine. But when tried to logged in for the second time, nothing happens. Just showing the progress dialog and then dismissing it.

Please help me on this.

Comment: What tools are you using? The Android SDK? Any clients/wrappers/libraries, like the one made by kaaes?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get metadata through the web-api. So basically you need to make the me (`GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`) call to get the logged in user object. See this [link](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/) for more details. Secondly, when you log in successfully through the SDK you get back a token and the time for how long this token is valid (1 hour). One approach to know if the token is still valid is to store current system time plus the length of time the token is valid and to check that every time you need to make a call with the token. You can always make another authentication call and get a new token, and since the authentication info is cached it doesn't require the user to login again. If however you require a single token that remains valid for more than an hour you will need to use the web api to retrieve a refreshable token.